# Unity - WWWForm not posting variables

Tags: unity-game-engine, x-www-form-urlencoded

I have this working just fine in one project however in a second project my _POST variables are blank. Thoughts?

```
IEnumerator GetClub()
     {
         Debug.Log("GetClub: - START");
         WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
         form.AddField("state", "TX");
         form.AddField("author", "MYNAME");
 
         UnityWebRequest res = UnityWebRequest.Post(getGlubsURL, form);
 
         yield return res.SendWebRequest();
 
         Debug.Log(res.downloadHandler.text);
```

and the php file is a simple

```
<?php
 echo "MADE IT  ";
 echo "author: [" . $_POST['author'] . "] ";
 echo "state: [" . $_POST['state'] . "]";
 ?>
```

and console in unity is:

MADE IT author: [] state: []
UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)

This works fine in POSTMAN so not sure why Unity Forms are not passing POST variables?

Comment: Other than you dont check if there is an error.   Which seems a likely culprit give the “made it” is missing

Comment: What errors would you suggest I be checking

Comment: The ones from your web call.

Comment: Where and what API am I not checking for errors?

Comment: Seriously look up the documentation on making web calls. We arent here to train you

Comment: @BugFinder my apologies..that is why I'm here asking.. I have been in the documentation and multiple paths for days on end.. that’s why I'm asking here.  I tried res.error however it is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been through a similar problem; $_POST is empty in general.

Then I found out that the URL was `"HTTP://website.com/folder"`, not `"HTTP://website.com/folder/"`. That last `"/`" is important apparently because without it, you'd get a `"PAGE MOVED PERMANENTLY"` error then redirect you to `"HTTP://website.com/folder/index.php"` discarding previous POST request.